# How to monitor file changes within a Java EE application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, filesystems, monitoring, portability

Is there a portable way of monitoring a file for changes from a deployed application?

As a practical example, suppose that I have an application deployed in a Glassfish AS. Then, as the application runs, I deploy a configuration file inside /META-INF, which will be read by some Thread from my application.

So, how to implement this? How to monitor a file (or a directory, for that matter) for changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be impossible to provide such a mechanism. You are assuming "/META-INF" is on the file system, but i don't believe there is any requirement for a Java EE application to be exploded to the filesystem.  (yes, many app servers do that for a variety of good reasons, but i'm pretty sure that is not a requirement).

Comment: Is there a way of getting the files under META-INF without invoking getClass().getResourceAsStream()?

Answer (score 4):

Java7 has a platform independent solution to monitor files in the filesystem:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html

Here is a short tutorial on how to use it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

But as jtahlborn has correctly said, if the container does not explode the .war file, there is nothing to watch.

Answer (score 1):

Classloaders cache heavily and a resource when first read is not updated anymore from the underlying filesystem.

Regardless, you are not allowed to access and manipulate the file system in pure Java EE.  The reason is simple - if your thread is migrated to another node (for clustered serveres) your files will not be available anymore.  The container must know about these things so it can handle them properly, and filesystems are not one of "these things".

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer from @jtahlborn. If you do have access to the filesystem, then you have two choices:

- The portable inefficient way is to periodically poll the filesystem and check for changes, either by checking the modification date or CRCins the file (slower)
- The efficient way is to use the native OS functionalities to be notified when the file changes. Check out [libnotify](http://skaba.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/bringing-libnotify-to-java/). It's going to require local native libraries, however.